# Is it possible to create Search without consolidated exchange rate via SuiteScript 1.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

How do I create a saved search via SuiteScript 1.0 with consolidated exchange rate set to NONE? I can easily do that in Saved Search UI and suitescript 2.0 a well, however, I can't find a way to do this via SuiteScript 1.0.
[image]

Make this (red circled field) NONE from script.

Answer (score 0):

meaning you want transaction whose consolidated exchange rate field is empty ?

Comment: No, actually there is a field (named: CONSOLIDATED EXCHANGE RATE) in saved search once we are creating/editing it. there is a way to edit change that field through suitescrip2.0 but i cant find anything in 1.0.

Edited the post to show u the field.